How mask out a colour from a texture and then semiprocedual/-random change the hue to specified colours on a colorramp
I want to change the red part of the texture (seen in the preview, which is the roof of the building) to another specified distribution along a colour ramp, so every copy/instance get another colour.
My approach was to mask out and use it as a factor, but I miss some nodes to make it work.
What would be a robust setup, that I can also use with other textures?

